# A few questions about the incident in Ramayana where Shri Hanuman brings a mountain to cure Shri Lakshmana

Tags: ramayana, hanuman, lakshmana

How did Shri Hanuman recognise the right mountain out of so many mountains where Sanjivani is?

What happened to the mountain after Sanjivani was extracted and used?

Wouldn't it be a problem in having a mountain in the middle of the battlefield? Was it not against the rules of war at the time?

Was it not dangerous to the lives of other plants, insects etc on the mountain to be moved from a cold climate of Himalayas into a tropical climate of Sri Lanka overnight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Question 1: Recognition of the mountain of herbs

Hanumanji recognised the mountain of herbs because the description of it was given to him as follows:-

> Prepare to cross far above the great path of the ocean in order to reach Himavat, the highest of mountains, O Hanuman, and there direct your course to that golden Peak Rishabha, difficult to scale and of an extreme altitude. There the summit of Mount Kailasha will be seen by you, O Slayer of Your Foes! **Between the peaks of these two mountains, you will behold the mountain of medicinal herbs rising in unparalleled splendour**, where every kind of healing plant abounds. 
> -*Śrimad Ramayana, Yuddha Kanda, Chapter 74, verses 29-31*

#### Question 2: After-story of the mountain

The mountain was returned to where it was gotten from by Hanumanji:

> Meantime the son of the Bearer of Fragrance, Hanuman, of formidable bounds, **carried the peak of medicinal herbs back to Himavat** and returned with speed to rejoin Rama.
> -*Śrimad Ramayana, Yuddha Kanda, Chapter 74, verse 77*

#### Question 3: Having a mountain in the middle of the battlefield

No, having a mountain in the middle of the battlefield was not problematic because a great part of the war itself was fought by the monkeys throwing mountains/ mountain peeks and trees on Rakshasas. One example is as follows:

> Hanuman placed himself in the way *armed with the peak of a mountain**, and, in fury struck Kumbhakama a violent blow, who, in his appalling corpulence, appeared like a hill.
> -*Śrimad Ramayana, Yuddha Kanda, Chapter 67, verse 17*

#### Question 4: danger to Flora and Fauna

I don’t think this question holds good as the mountain was brought temporarily to Lanka and duly returned back later. It wouldn’t have caused much harm. There is no mention in the book, so I can’t comment.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Very insightful!